# EV of sequences of coin flips

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a biased coin $C$ where $P(H) = p$ and $P(T) = 1-p$. This coin could be tossed an infinite number of times and the results will be recorded.

I want to calculate the probability of a given sequence to appear.

A sequence is a set of coin flips that have the same result, eg: the run $HHHTTHHH$ have 2 sequences of 3 heads and 1 sequence of 2 tails

How do I calculate the probability of a sequence?

**EDIT**

One of the major problems i have are when i try to calculate the probability of any sequence of 0, that means $P(T, 0) + P(H, 0)$ which is $P(H) + P(T) = p + (1-p) = 1$ so how do other sequences can have any probability?

**EDIT 2**

Each run could have any size we want. The problem I have to solve is: In a run of size $n$ how many sequences of length $s$ are expected

If the length of the sequence is bigger then the length of the run the chance is 0, but otherwise it grows and get to 1

eg: $p=0.5$, run length is 100 flips, sequence of exactly 1 head have 50% chance of happening and 100% probability of appearing **at least** one time in that run, but how many times is this sequence expected to appear in that run? (not how many times it did appear, how many times it should appear)

My biggest problem is because a run of 100 flips does not have 100 events (sequences) the same run could have 1 event or 10 or 100

Comment: Which specific sequence do you have in mind?

Comment: I want to calculate the probability of sequences lower then 5 heads, so a sum of P(0) + P(1) + P(2) + P(3) + P(4) + P(5) is also ok

Comment: Let $0\lt p\lt 1$. The probability that the sequence HHHHHH will appear in the sequence is $1$. I do not know what random variable you want the EV (expected value?) of.

Comment: the sequence HHHHHH have $p^6$ probability of happen and you are taking just one sequence in consideration, that same run could have been HHTHHT

Comment: I think André is pointing out that you didn't say how many flips you're looking at.  If, for instance, you only flip the coin six times, then the probability that HHHHHH appears is indeed $p^6$.  But if you flip the coin seven times, the probability increases to $p^7+2p^6(1-p) = 2p^6-p^7 > p^6$.  In the limit, as the number of flips increases without bound, the probability that HHHHHH appears approaches one.  So, how many times are you flipping the coin?

Comment: edited question to answer @BrianTung

Comment: When you say you want the probability of a given sequence to appear, do you necessarily mean a "run" of consecutive heads or tails?  Or do you mean any possible sequence?  For instance, would you be interested in the probability that the sequence HTTHTTHTT appears in $100$ flips?